# diferente vs. otro/otra

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, gramática, adjetivos

I'm a bit confused about the differences in use of `diferente` and `otro`/`otra`. For example, I want to say *"I'm a programmer like Javier, but I work for a different company."* Would that be

- *Soy un programador como Javier, pero trabajo por una empresa diferente.*
- *Soy un programador como Javier, pero trabajo por una otra empresa.*

or something else entirely? And why so? When is which word used?

Comment: Note that you work ***para*** *una empresa*, not ***por*** *una empresa*.

Comment: @Flimzy Yes, that was noted in the answer. I find those two confusing... Luckily there's a question and a great answer on that very topic already.

Comment: Indeed, por vs. para is confusing for most people learning Spanish from English. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both ways are completely correct and can be used the same way to express what you meant in English. In other words: there are synonyms.

Maybe you can understand it better with this translation into English:

*...pero trabajo para otra empresa*  -->  *but I work for **another** company*.

However, be careful because you made a different mistake: As you can see above the correct wording would be:
 "*para otra*" instead of "*por una otra*".

Comment: Ah, para and por... Those two confuse me too, yes. But luckily there's already a question on that, I'll just have to read the answer again. :-D

Comment: So, it could be *"...para una empresa diferente"* or *"...para otra empresa"*, is that correct?

Comment: @blalasaadri Correct. It can be used both ways with the same meaning.